# Validity of Certificate Installer, after removing the application from Play Market

Tags: android, google-play, certificate

I have an application in Play Market, which I distribute at the same time using .apk files signed by Google Certificate Installer. Will be valid Certificate Installer, if the market decides that my program violates the rules and deletes it? Will I be able to use it to install via .apk?